# Mouse clicks twice but I want to click once

Tags: windows-10, drivers, mouse

My wireless mouse (HAMA 00134944) clicks twice in Windows 10, but I clicked only once. Windows 10 recognize the mouse as HID compatible mouse. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: does this happen with other mice?

Comment: @MMM no, and this mouse also works correctly with other windows10 machine, and the same driver.